# Return line with matched word and the line following it and list by order descending

Tags: javascript, regex

Just to be clear, I need help with `JavaScript`, not `Powershell`. My example below in `Powershell` is only for demonstration.

What I want to achieve in `Javascript` is to return the line which contains the matching word **banana** and the line following it, and finally list by order descending.

**Example input data:**

> 2018-01-01 Product: Apple Some text
>
> 2018-01-01 Price: Euro 1 Some text
>
> 2018-01-02 Product: Banana Some text
>
> 2018-01-02 Price: Euro 3 Some text
>
> 2018-01-03 Product: Orange Some text
>
> 2018-01-03 Price: Euro 4 Some text
>
> 2018-01-04 Product: Banana Some text
>
> 2018-01-04 Price: Euro 1 Some text

**This works for me in Powershell:**

```
$input = Get-Content -Path $inputRaw | Select-String -Pattern "banana (.*)" -Context 0,1
$input | Group-Object -Property Name | Sort-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object} > $output
```

**The result in variable output should be:**

> 2018-01-02 Product: Banana Some text
>
> 2018-01-02 Price: Euro 3 Some text
>
> 2018-01-04 Product: Banana Some text
>
> 2018-01-04 Price: Euro 1 Some text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to to create a new array of items by finding the line with `Bananas` and the line after, and pushing them onto the new array.

```js
const input = `2018-01-01 Product: Apple Some text
2018-01-01 Price: Euro 1 Some text
2018-01-02 Product: Banana Some text
2018-01-02 Price: Euro 3 Some text
2018-01-03 Product: Orange Some text
2018-01-03 Price: Euro 4 Some text
2018-01-04 Product: Banana Some text
2018-01-04 Price: Euro 1 Some text
2018-01-04 Product: Apple Some text
2018-01-04 Price: Euro 1 Some text
2018-01-04 Product: Pear Some text
2018-01-04 Price: Euro 1 Some text`;

function find(text, ...words) {
  return text.split(/\r\n|\n/).reduce((arr, val, idx, orig) => {
    return words.some(w => val.includes(w)) ? arr.concat(orig[idx], orig[idx + 1]) : arr
  }, [])
}

document.querySelector('textarea').value = find(input, 'Banana', 'Orange').join('\n')
console.log(find(input, 'Pear'))
```

```html
<textarea rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
```

### Edit

You can pass an array of words to the function (I used the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) method with not much support for IE if needed), I then use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on those words to check if atleast one of the items matches the string.

Comment: Hi, thanks! This seems to be working well. But I am not sure how to pass it to a variable? Instead of showing it in the console. I would like for the result to be stored in variable output and display that content in my textbox like this: textarea.value = output;

Comment: `document.getElementById('my-textarea').value = find('Orange')`

Comment: Would it be possible to combine both (Orange and Banana) at the same time? e.g. 
.value('Orange'|'Banana'), so that I have all of the result in the same array?

Comment: Yes you can, see my updated code and my **edit note** underneath the code.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly, like this: .value = find(input, 'Orange', 'Banana'). I should probably open a new ticket for this next question, but I ran into another problem. Each line is divided by ',' and displayed as one long line. I would like to replace each ',' with '\n'. I tried this by passing the array to a variable and using split and join, but it gives me no result in the textbox. Do you know how I can fix it? If I remember this worked earlier in your first example, but I could remember wrong: varName.split(',').join('\n')

Comment: This returns an array, so you shouldn't have to use `split()` unless your using `toString()` before you split. You should just need to use `join()`. If you are outputting as html use `join('<br>')`, but if your inserting into a `<pre>` or `<textarea>` then `\n` is fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me solve all of the issues. Really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pure regex solution by using this regex:

```
/(^.*?Banana.*\n)(.*?$)/gm
```

It will match the first sentence with 'Banana' and the rest of the line, then add the following line.

You can grap each line if you want at index `'1'` and `'2'`.

Use it like this (assuming your string is called `'text'`):

```
var  match = text.match(/(^.*?Banana.*\n)(.*?$)/gm);
var firstPart = match[1];
var secondPart = match[2];
```

**Edit**:

To use a variable instead of hardcoding 'banana', you can use the string constructor for regex (assuming your var is called `'fruit'`:

```
var regex =new RegExp('(^.*?' + fruit + '.*\\n)(.*?$)','gm');
```

Comment: Thanks Poul, this looks interesting, I will try it out! :)